# Question about de Bruĳn Notation of lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4110/2016fa/lectures/lecture15.pdf

> One way to avoid the tricky interaction between free and bound names
> in the substitution operator is to pick a representation for
> expressions that doesn’t have any names at all! Intuitively, we can
> think of a bound variable is just a pointer to the λ that binds it.
> For example, in λx.λy.y x, the y points to the first λ and the x
> points to the second λ.

The expression `λx.λy.y x` gets a whitespace between `y` and `x`.
Should I ignore that whitespace, and see it as `λx.(λy.yx)` ?
Or `λx.((λy.y)x)` ?

> The y points to the first λ and the x points to the second λ.

The first `λ` on the left, its bound variable is `x`, why does it say *y points to the first λ*?
And same question for the second `λ` on the right, why does it say *the x points to the second λ* while `y` is its bound variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, the scope of a $\lambda$ extends all the way to the right, unless parentheses state otherwise. So, the expression $\lambda x.\lambda y. y\,x$ should be interpreted as $\lambda x.(\lambda y. y\,x)$.

For the de Bruijn representation, you should count the number of *nested* $\lambda$s from the point where the variable appears and *outwards*. So, in $\lambda x.\lambda y. y\,x$, from $y$ you count only one $\lambda$ until you reach $\lambda y$, and from $x$, you count two $\lambda$ until you reach $\lambda x$.
So, the de Bruijn conversion yields $\lambda.\lambda.0\,1$.

Beware that, when counting, you should exclude $\lambda$s whose scope ends before the variable's occurence. Take for example the expression $\lambda x.(\lambda y. y)\,x$. Like before, from $y$ you count only one $\lambda$ until $\lambda y$, but this time, from $x$ you count again only one $\lambda$ until you reach $\lambda x$, and that is because the scope of $\lambda y$ ends before $x$ appears. So, the de Bruijn conversion yields $\lambda.(\lambda.0)\,0$.